# How I change the default start path for cmd.exe in Windows 7 when opening from vim?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vim

cmd.exe starts in `%userprofile%` when I start it normally. When I start it from vim, it starts in `%systemroot%\system32`.

How can I change this so it starts in a folder of my choice (from vim)?

Comment: Which version of vim?  This is not the behaviour of the `:shell` command within vim version 7.2, which quite happily spawns the command interpreter in whatever directory vim is itself in at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Navigate to the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor and search for the String Autorun in the right window. If that string is not existing yet create it as a "String Value". Double-click it afterwards and add the new directory path in the following way:
>
> CD /d %systemroot%\system32

[Source](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/11/16/change-the-default-command-prompt-directory/)

It looks like cmd.exe isn't using %systemroot%\system32 as it's starting path when running from vim.  %systemroot%\system32 is just where cmd.exe is located.  The working directory is still the same as when starting cmd normally.

Comment: +1 even though you deleted it.

Comment: I deleted it because I answered the question I perceived and not the question that was asked.  It seems like the answer still applies though.  Sorry for the confusion.